# Which is better to use, mixin or static method for organizing long code

Tags: typescript

I have a class which contains long code, and now I want to organize the codes into separate file.

I have 2 ideas, using Mixin and using static method.

For example,

```
class myController {
    routeSubView(type: SubViewType, params: any) {
        swtich(type) {
            case SubViewType.A: 
                this._showA(params);
                break;
            case SubViewType.B: 
                this._showB(params);
                break;
            case SubViewType.C: 
                this._showC(params);
                break;
            case SubViewType.D: 
                this._showD(params);
                break;
            // ... a lot more
        }
    }

    private _showA() {
        // initialize view and render
    }

    private _showB() {
        // initialize view and render
    }

    private _showC() {
        // initialize view and render
    }

    private _showD() {
        // initialize view and render
    }

    // ... a lot more
}
```

**#idea1 ) Move generating sub-view codes to static class**

```
### sub_views.ts
class SubViews {
    static showA(params: any) {
        // initialize view and render
    }
    static showB(params: any) {
        // initialize view and render
    }
}

### my_controller.ts
import { SubViews } from './sub_views';
class myController {
    routeSubView(type: SubViewType, params: any) {
        swtich(type) {
            case SubViewType.A: 
                SubViews::showA();
                break;
            case SubViewType.B: 
                SubViews::showB();
                break;
            case SubViewType.C: 
                SubViews::showC();
                break;
            case SubViewType.D: 
                SubViews::showD();
                break;
            // ... a lot more
        }
    }
}
```

**#idea2) using Mixin**

```
### mixin.ts
export interface ISubviews {
    _showA(params: any): any;
    _showB(params: any): any;
    _showC(params: any): any;
    _showD(params: any): any;
}

export function _showA(param: any){
    // initialize view and render
}
export function _showB(param: any){
    // initialize view and render
}
export function _showC(param: any){
    // initialize view and render
}
export function _showD(param: any){
    // initialize view and render
}

### my_controller.ts

import * as { Mixin } from './mixin';

class myController implement Mixin.ISubviews {
    _showA(params: any): any;
    _showB(params: any): any;
    _showC(params: any): any;
    _showD(params: any): any;

    /// ...
}

Cocktail.mixin(myController, Mixin);
```

Which is better idea? or any other better idea? please advice me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript and Typescript are prototypal languages, meaning they split the more classical OO model into embedding, delegation and creation. This allows you to express certain powerful concepts that don't exist in the classical model. Your first example is more akin to a workaround in classical OO, where you prefer composition over inheritance.

In prototypal languages, composition is still preferable to inheritance, but you can express it more directly, for example through a mixin (embedding concept). I think you should probably always prefer a mixin over member composition.

If you want to dive deeper into these concepts, watch [Eric Elliot's talk about the three types of prototypal inheritance](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/3-different-kinds-of-prototypal-inheritance-es6-edition-32d777fa16c9#.28m3egwbh) and if you want to go even deeper, check out [Luca Cardelli's A Theory of Objects](http://lucacardelli.name/theoryofobjects.html).

Comment: I just done using mixin. I will watch and read the reference too, thank you!