# TypeScript: class composition

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, composition, ecmascript-2016

Based on this awesome [Composition over Inheritance](https://youtu.be/wfMtDGfHWpA) video by MPJ, I've been trying to formulate composition in TypeScript. I want to compose **classes**, not objects or factory functions. Here is my effort so far (with a little help from *lodash*):

```
class Barker {
  constructor(private state) {}

  bark() {
    console.log(`Woof, I am ${this.state.name}`);
  }
}

class Driver {
  constructor(private state) {}

  drive() {
    this.state.position = this.state.position + this.state.speed;
  }
}

class Killer {
  constructor(private state) {}

  kill() {
    console.log(`Burn the ${this.state.prey}`);
  }
}

class MurderRobotDog {
  constructor(private state) {
    return _.assignIn(
      {},
      new Killer(state),
      new Driver(state),
      new Barker(state)
    );
  }
}

const metalhead = new MurderRobotDog({ 
  name: 'Metalhead', 
  position: 0, 
  speed: 100, 
  prey: 'witch' 
});

metalhead.bark(); // expected: "Woof, I am Metalhead"
metalhead.kill(); // expected: "Burn the witch"
```

This resulting in:

> TS2339: Property 'bark' does not exist on type 'MurderRobotDog'
>
> TS2339: Property 'kill' does not exist on type 'MurderRobotDog'

What's the right way of doing class composition in TypeScript?

Comment: I have no idea what `_.assignIn` is, but this looks much more like mixins than composition. And no, you cannot easily mix multiple `class`es

Comment: @Bergi https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#assignIn. And yes, my effort goes around this answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39243098/2013891 - which suggests we should probably always prefer a mixin over member composition in prototypical language. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: MPJ got composition completely wrong, and actual composition never once made an appearance in his video.  What you're looking for is called multiple inheritance or mixins. https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/5dxq6i/composition_over_inheritance/da8bplv/

Comment: @GlennMohammad ... but do you also know why a `MurderRobotDog` instance does not feature any of the expected (prototypal) methods? And / or did you already read the JavaScript code which your TS was transpiled to?

Comment: @JeffM Thanks for the great pointer! The thread really opens up my mind about what actual composition is. ❤︎ I always thought mixin is a form of composition.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I suppose it's because of the lodash's _.assignIn. :$ The methods are in the MurderRobotDog instance's object, but not in its prototype. And yes, I read it already. The method is correctly transpiled to the prototype of the classes to be composed (i.e. `Barker`, `Driver`, and `Killer`).

Answer (score 12):

#### Composition vs Inheritance

I think we should make a distinction between composition and inheritance and reconsider what we are trying to achieve. As a commenter pointed out, what MPJ does is actually an example of using mixins. This is basically a form of inheritance, adding implementation on the target object (mixing).

#### Multiple inheritance

I tried to come up with a neat way to do this and this is my best suggestion:

```
type Constructor<I extends Base> = new (...args: any[]) => I;

class Base {}

function Flies<T extends Constructor<Base>>(constructor: T = Base as any) {
  return class extends constructor implements IFlies {
    public fly() {
      console.log("Hi, I fly!");
    }
  };
}

function Quacks<T extends Constructor<Base>>(constructor: T = Base as any) {
  return class extends constructor implements ICanQuack {
    public quack(this: IHasSound, loud: boolean) {
      console.log(loud ? this.sound.toUpperCase() : this.sound);
    }
  };
}

interface IHasSound {
  sound: string;
}

interface ICanQuack {
  quack(loud: boolean): void;
}

interface IQuacks extends IHasSound, ICanQuack {}

interface IFlies {
  fly(): void;
}

class MonsterDuck extends Quacks(Flies()) implements IQuacks, IFlies {
  public sound = "quackly!!!";
}

class RubberDuck extends Quacks() implements IQuacks {
  public sound = "quack";
}

const monsterDuck = new MonsterDuck();
monsterDuck.quack(true); // "QUACKLY!!!"
monsterDuck.fly(); // "Hi, I fly!"

const rubberDuck = new RubberDuck();
rubberDuck.quack(false); // "quack"
```

The benefit of using this approach is that you can allow access to certain properties of the owner object in the implementation of the inherited methods. Although a bit better naming could be use, I see this as a very potential solution.

#### Composition

Composition is instead of mixing the functions into the object, we set what behaviours should be contained in it instead, and then implement these as self-contained libraries inside the object.

```
interface IQuackBehaviour {
  quack(): void;
}

interface IFlyBehaviour {
  fly(): void;
}

class NormalQuack implements IQuackBehaviour {
  public quack() {
    console.log("quack");
  }
}

class MonsterQuack implements IQuackBehaviour {
  public quack() {
    console.log("QUACK!!!");
  }
}

class FlyWithWings implements IFlyBehaviour {
  public fly() {
    console.log("I am flying with wings");
  }
}

class CannotFly implements IFlyBehaviour {
  public fly() {
    console.log("Sorry! Cannot fly");
  }
}

interface IDuck {
  flyBehaviour: IFlyBehaviour;
  quackBehaviour: IQuackBehaviour;
}

class MonsterDuck implements IDuck {
  constructor(
    public flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings(),
    public quackBehaviour = new MonsterQuack()
  ) {}
}

class RubberDuck implements IDuck {
  constructor(
    public flyBehaviour = new CannotFly(),
    public quackBehaviour = new NormalQuack()
  ) {}
}

const monsterDuck = new MonsterDuck();
monsterDuck.quackBehaviour.quack(); // "QUACK!!!"
monsterDuck.flyBehaviour.fly(); // "I am flying with wings"

const rubberDuck = new RubberDuck();
rubberDuck.quackBehaviour.quack(); // "quack"
```

As you can see, the practical difference is that the composites doesn't know of any properties existing on the object using it. This is probably a good thing, as it conforms to the principle of Composition over Inheritance.

Comment: This is not at all what is meant by composition. The `implements` in typescript only ensures that a class conforms to a sub-type (e.g., has the variable `foo` or the function `bar`). Composition, on the other hand, does this as well but goes a step further by ensuring the class also conforms to implementation, i.e., composition **gives** the class the sub-type and implementation... e,g, we can ensure a class gets the variable `foo` with default value of 1. Typescript doesn't currently support this natively, but you can partially implement composition with mixins.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this. There is currently a proposal to allow for the `extends` keyword to allow you to do this, but it is still being talked about in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16936).

Your only other option is to use the [Mixins functionality](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) available in TypeScript, but the problem with that approach is that you have to re-define each function or method that you want to re-use from the "inherited" classes.

Comment: @th3n3wgy it looks like the github issue you pointed to is regarding interfaces. I couldn't find anything similar related to class composition